# How to search in more than one column of the database using cakephp

Tags: php, select, cakephp-2.0

Good morning,

I need some help in a survey, which I am not able to do.
  Imagine a web application (php), which makes use cakephp.
  In this application I have a search field, one normal input.
  And imagine that this application has a table in the database with 3 fields, (produtoNome), (categoria), (tags).

how can this research below, I already search for table field (produtoNome).

```
  $this->Anuncio->find('all',array('conditions' => array('produtoNome'=> array('$regex' => (string)$pesq))));
```

The question is:

How can I do a search, that search the 3 fields of the table not only one?

In other words, when someone types something into the search field, it will perform this search in more than one field of the table.

I tried this:

```
$produtos = $this->Anuncio->find('all',
            array('conditions' => 
              array('OR' =>
                 array(
                   array('produtoNome'=> array('$regex' => (string)$pesq)),
                   array('categoria'=> array('$regex' => (string)$pesq))
                 )
              ),
            )
          );
```

but does not work. Returns nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I got to do this research.
  To work, so I had to modify the 'OR' to '$or'

Answer (score 0):

```
$produtos = $this->Anuncio->find('all',
        array('conditions' => 
          array('OR' =>
             array(
               'produtoNome'=> array('$regex' => (string)$pesq),
               'categoria'=> array('$regex' => (string)$pesq)
             )
          ),
        )
      );
```

Not sure, but this should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I would love to see the query from cake.

Never seen that '$regex' syntax for cake, can't find it in documentation, can't find any reference on the internet - where did you get that from? I'm using cake quite a while now and never came about that (though I never needed regexp for queries)

[sorry, low reputation, could not put this on a comment]

Comment: hello lars,  I'm using a database MongoDB.

Comment: well, that explains a lot ;)